# Router (and masquerade) only from specific IP

Tags: linux, networking, router

I want all traffic coming from 192.168.2.10 on interface eth0 to be masqueraded and forwarded out through interface tun0. I want the response to come back through tun0. I don't want other traffic on interface eth0 to be affected. This is what I have:

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -s 192.168.2.10/32 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
# ip rule add from 192.168.2.10/32 table 100
# ip route add default via 10.8.0.1 table 100
```

Is this configuration correct? It appears to be working but traffic looks very strange in iftop . It looks like the outgoing traffic is going through tun0 but the response is coming on eth0, although I may be reading it wrong or it may be caused by misconfiguration on the other end.

Comment: What you are trying to do is, effectively, to use two routing tables, one for 192.168..2.10 and another one for everything else. This can be achieved, but `iptables` has nothing to do with it. This is called `policy routing` or `source routing`. You can start by reading this, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22770/two-interfaces-two-addresses-two-gateways

Comment: Thanks, my understanding is that the first iptables line ensures packets going out tun0 are masqueraded (they have to be, 192.168.2.10 is not a valid IP for this interface). The next two lines are policy rules allowing the packets to flow between the two interfaces (i.e. if I don't have them packets will be dropped, no?) and the ip rule & route sets that packets from 192.168.2.10 should use 10.8.0.1 as gateway independent of the default gateway. Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly change through which interface the replies come in – *the recipient doesn't make that decision,* the sender does (as well as the intermediaries).

You should however make sure the *outgoing* packets are being masqueraded with the correct source address. If it's not the right one, consider using `-j SNAT` with an explicitly configured source address, instead of relying on `-j MASQUERADE` autoselection.

In other words, to make replies come in via tun0, the original packets must have a 'source' address that would normally be reached via tun0 as well.

Comment: Is there any way I can verify if it's working with tcpdump? If I do: tcpdump on interface tun0 I see the traffic is correctly masqueraded. However, if I do a tcpdump on eth0 I see packets with src 192.168.2.10 and target the external IP where the packet should go after it gets forwarded through tun0. Is this as expected?

Comment: Well, the packet cannot be processed by iptables _before_ it's received... so a dump on eth0 will of course show 'original' packets.

Comment: Alright. It appears to work fine. Unless you have a better suggestion I will accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Well, the suggestion remains – figure out how to change where the remote end _sends_ the replies. Or the routers in between.

Comment: The remote end sends the replies to tun0, it's working as expected. I was confused by the 'original' packets on eth0 but your explanation makes sense.